# How i can override AdminEmployeesController in prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, module, overriding, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to override AdminEmployeesController to send email to employee after creating his account automatically.
When i override this class i get:
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'type' (T_STRING)

I have searched on the net a lot of time, but i didn't find the solution yet.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your `php` code. What is your code?

Comment: i have just extended the class AdminEmployeesControllerCore :class AdminEmployeesController extends AdminEmployeesControllerCore
{
   
}

Comment: What is your file path & name? Please copy & paste FULL your code, for you have error in `php` code.

Comment: path : modules/my_module/override/controllers/admin/AdminEmployeesController.php. i have tested without putting any code in overrided class

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I delete my file overrided in www/override

in order to reinstate the default behavior, i delete the /cache/class_index.php file

Everything works fine now